# Manual vim code folds keep moving

Tags: vim, code-folding

I prefer to make my code folds manually. However, I've noticed that the folds move after I

1. Make the fold using `zf`
2. Make some deletes/inserts after/below the code fold

The folds "move" in the sense that if 51 lines were folded, after movement only 50 lines are now folded. This makes it so that part of the code that was folded is no longer in the fold and now just looks like a randomly placed piece of code. I often have to delete the moved fold and do a refold.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Please let me know if this didn't make any sense or if you can't replicate this behavior.

```
set nocompatible " required
filetype off     " required

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" ==================== Begin my added plugins ====================="

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'luochen1990/rainbow'
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
    Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
    Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
    Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plugin 'aperezdc/vim-template'
Plugin 'tpope/tpope-vim-abolish'
Plugin 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" ===================== End my added plugins ======================"

if v:lang =~ "utf8$" || v:lang =~ "UTF-8$"
   set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
endif

set bs=indent,eol,start     " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set ai                      " always set autoindenting on
set viminfo='20,\"50        " read/write a .viminfo file, don't store more than 50 lines of registers
set history=50              " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler                   " show the cursor position all the time

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands
if has("autocmd")
  augroup fedora
  autocmd!
  " In text files, always limit the width of text to 78 characters
  " autocmd BufRead *.txt set tw=78
  " When editing a file, always jump to the last cursor position
  autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line ("'\"") <= line("$") |
  \   exe "normal! g'\"" |
  \ endif
  " don't write swapfile on most commonly used directories for NFS mounts or USB sticks
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPre /media/*,/run/media/*,/mnt/* set directory=~/tmp,/var/tmp,/tmp
  " start with spec file template
  autocmd BufNewFile *.spec 0r /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/template.spec
  " auto-source the vimrc upon writing to the file
  autocmd bufwritepost vimrc source %
  augroup END
endif

if has("cscope") && filereadable("/usr/bin/cscope")
   set csprg=/usr/bin/cscope
   set csto=0
   set cst
   set nocsverb
   " add any database in current directory
   if filereadable("cscope.out")
      cs add $PWD/cscope.out
   " else add database pointed to by environment
   elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
      cs add $CSCOPE_DB
   endif
   set csverb
endif

syntax enable

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" ============== Begin additions for Syntastic plugin ============="

let &shellpipe = '2>&1| tee'
let &shellredir = '>%s 2>&1'

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

"let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 2
"let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
"let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
"let g:syntastic_enable_balloons = 0
"let g:syntastic_error_symbol = '✗'
"let g:syntastic_ignore_files = ['\.min\.js$', '\.min\.css$']
"let g:syntastic_loc_list_height = 5
"let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = '✗'
"let g:syntastic_style_error_symbol = '∆'
"let g:syntastic_style_warning_symbol = '∆'

" shortcut command for toggling syntastic mode (useful for when I'm just writing test code)
fun! s:toggle_syntastic()
    call SyntasticToggleMode()
endfun
command! STM :call s:toggle_syntastic()

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" =========== Begin additions for Rainbow_parens plugin ==========="

" set to zero and use :RainbowToggle to switch between modes
let g:rainbow_active = 1

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" =========== Begin additions for Tabular plugin ==========="

vnoremap ;t :Tabularize /

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" =========== Begin additions for SnipMate plugin ==========="

let g:snippet_version = 1

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" ============== Begin additions for Templates plugin ============="

" see :h template.txt

" let g:templates_user_variables = [
"   \   ['FULLPATH', 'GetFullPath'],
"   \ ]
" 
" function! GetFullPath()
"   return expand('%:p')
" endfunction

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" ================== Begin my 'set' vimrc things =================="

" Show (partial) command in status line
set showcmd

" Do case insensitive matching, smart case matching, don't wrap back to the top after searching
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set nowrapscan
set incsearch

" Automatically save before commands like :make
set autowrite

" Hide buffers when they are abandoned
set hidden

" set tab length, indentation length, auto indent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent

" disable swap file generation
set noswapfile

" change the orientation of the windows when using :split and :vs
set splitbelow
set splitright

" save state of original code folds, don't open code folds when doing searches
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
set foldopen-=search
set viewoptions=folds,cursor

" auto comments for /* (javadoc style comments)
set comments=sl:/*,mb:\ *,elx:\ */

" lets the tags file to be in a separate directory from the source code
" basically does the following:
"   goes up one directory at a time until it finds a file called '.tags'
set tags=.tags;/

" set manual fold method, min number of lines to make a fold = 1
set fdm=manual
set fml=1

" fold method based on file syntax
" fold level    = 2 for .java    = 1 for .c
" min fold level = 0 for folding single lines
"set fdm=syntax
"set fml=0
"if &filetype == 'java'
"   set fdn=2
"elseif &filetype == 'c'
"   set fdn=1
"endif

" searches down into subfolders
" provides tab-completion for all file-related tasks
set path+=**

" display all matching files when you tab-complete
set wildmenu

" tweaks for file browsing
let g:netrw_browse_split=4   " open in prior window
let g:netrw_altv=1           " open splits to the right
let g:netrw_liststyle=3      " tree view

" set matching parenthesis/brace/bracket to be underlined
hi MatchParen cterm=underline ctermbg=none ctermfg=none

" make the vim tab bar look prettier
hi TabLineFill ctermfg=Black ctermbg=Black
hi TabLine     ctermfg=Blue  ctermbg=Black
hi TabLineSel  ctermfg=Black ctermbg=Yellow
hi Title       ctermfg=Black ctermbg=Yellow

" set variable 'g:os' according to development environment
if !exists('g:os')
    if has('win32') || has('win16')
        let g:os = 'Windows'
    else
        let g:os = substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '')
    endif
endif

" a godsend that disables that stupidly annoying beep/bell once and for all
if g:os =~ 'CYGWIN'
    set belloff=all
endif

" prevent ubuntu from outputting garbage characters
if g:os =~ 'Linux'
    set t_RV=
endif

" make the clipboard the default register
if has('unnamedplus')
    set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
else
    set clipboard=unnamed
endif

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" =============== Begin my 'nnoremaps' vimrc things ==============="

" typing '' now also centers the screen
nnoremap '' ''zz

" map the jump-to-mark command 'm so that the
" command centers the screen upon jumping
nnoremap 'm 'mzz

"" press % to visually highlight in-between brace/bracket/parentheses
noremap % v%

" press CTRL-j/CTRL-k to go down/up half a page, respectively
noremap <C-j> <C-D>
noremap <C-k> <C-U>

" capital K enters a linefeed while maintaining normal mode
nnoremap K i<CR><ESC>

" use CTRL-h and CTRL-L to switch between Vim tabs
nnoremap <C-h> gT
inoremap <C-h> <ESC>gT
nnoremap <C-l> gt
inoremap <C-l> <ESC>gt

" use , to repeat the last find command --> use shift, to go the other way
nnoremap , ;
vnoremap , ;
nnoremap < ,

" remap the normal paste to align the pasted block with the surrounded text
nnoremap p ]p
nnoremap P ]P

" remap yb to not move the cursor backwards (repositioning the cursor was annoying)
nnoremap yb ybw

" remap CTRL-n to move to the next line that has a compile error"
nnoremap <C-n> :cn<CR>

" remap CTRL-p to move to the previous line that has a compile error"
" NOTE: can also map this to CTRL-N
nnoremap <C-p> :cp<CR>

" mappings for easily deleting the surrounding brackets/parentheses
" ==========================================================================================================
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_df( dt(me%x`ex:silent! call repeat#set("\<plug>Map_df(", v:count)<cr>
nmap df( <Plug>Map_df(

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_d( me%x`ex:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Map_d(", v:count)<CR>
nmap d( <Plug>Map_d(`e

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_df[ dt[me%x`ex:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Map_df[", v:count)<CR>
nmap df[ <Plug>Map_df[`e

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_d[ me%x`ex:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Map_d[", v:count)<CR>
nmap d[ <Plug>Map_df[`e
" ==========================================================================================================

" mappings for easily changing the surrounding brackets/parentheses
" ==========================================================================================================
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_cf( dt(me%x`exi:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Map_cf(", v:count)<CR>
nmap cf( <Plug>Map_cf(`e

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_c( %me%r(`er)%:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Map_c(", v:count)<CR>
nmap c( <Plug>Map_c(`e

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_cf[ dt[me%x`exi:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Map_cf[", v:count)<CR>
nmap cf[ <Plug>Map_cf[`e

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_c[ %me%r[`er]%:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Map_c[", v:count)<CR>
nmap c[ <Plug>Map_c[`e
" ==========================================================================================================

" mappings for easily replacing the surrounding brackets/parentheses
" ==========================================================================================================
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_r( %me%r(`er)%:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Map_r(", v:count)<CR>
nmap r( <Plug>Map_r(`e

nnoremap <silent> <Plug>Map_r[ %me%r[`er]%:silent! call repeat#set("\<Plug>Map_r[", v:count)<CR>
nmap r[ <Plug>Map_r[`e
" ==========================================================================================================

" remap U to ~ for easier uppercasing/lowercasing
nnoremap U ~

" pressing Control-w then Control-c in split windows accidentally closes the window. I dislike this
nnoremap <C-w><C-c> <ESC>

" using 'x' will now put the 'cut' letter(s) in the black hole register "_ 
nnoremap x "_x
nnoremap X "_X

" using '' to will now put you at the (last cursor position) instead of the (last row your cursor was in)
nnoremap '' ``zz

" map Y to act the same as D & C
nnoremap Y y$

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" =============== Begin my 'inoremaps' vimrc things ==============="

" autocomplete for matching brace (activated upon pressing enter)
if g:os =~ 'CYGWIN'
    inoremap {<CR>  {<TAB><CR>}<Esc><Esc>O
elseif g:os =~ 'Linux'
    inoremap {<CR>  {<CR>}<ESC>O
endif

" DUMBEST HACK EVER (but I'm so happy it works)
" normally pressing CTRL-c undoes your auto-indent on a blank line
" solutions to this is to make a new line that is auto-indented for you
"   and then type some random character, delete it, then press CTRL-c
" so, that's exactly what this hack does
inoremap <C-c> l<BS><ESC>

" remap the paste function in insert mode to Control-p
inoremap <C-p> <C-R>*

" remap the autocomplete feature in vim to only look in the current file
inoremap <C-n> <C-x><C-n>

" remap the autocomplete feature for files to Control-m in insert mode
inoremap <C-k> <C-x><C-f>

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" =============== Begin my 'vnoremaps' vimrc things ==============="

" easier uppercasing/lowercasing
vnoremap U ~

" so that your default register won't be overwritten when you paste over stuff in visual mode
xnoremap p "_dP

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" ============== Begin some 'function' vimrc things ==============="

" now you can close the file, get back in, and still maintain the original undo tree
if has('persistent_undo')
    set undolevels=5000
    call system('mkdir ~/.vim/undo')
    set undodir=~/.vim/undo
    set undofile
endif

"=================================================================="

" toggle commented lines for #-style comments
function! ToggleComment_Py()
    if matchstr(getline(line(".")),'^\s*\#.*$') == ''
           :execute "s:^:# :"
    else
           :execute "s:^\s*# ::"
    endif
endfunction
vnoremap ;# :call ToggleComment_Py()<CR>
nnoremap ;# :call ToggleComment_Py()<CR>

" toggle commented lines for "-style comments
function! ToggleComment_Vimrc()
    if matchstr(getline(line(".")),'^\s*\".*$') == ''
           :execute 's:^:" :'
    else
           :execute 's:^\s*" ::'
    endif
endfunction
vnoremap ;" :call ToggleComment_Vimrc()<CR>
nnoremap ;" :call ToggleComment_Vimrc()<CR>

"=================================================================="

" reformat multiline if-statements into single line if-statements
fun! s:reformat(line1, line2)

    " Remember line locs and numbers (bookkeeping)
    execute 'normal!' 'me'
    let l:before = line('$')

    " Join the selected lines && put a newline before every 'else' 
    execute 'normal!' . (a:line2 - a:line1 + 1) . 'J' 
    execute 's/else/\relse/g'

    " Recalculate the range && run Tabular
    let l:line2 = a:line2 - (l:before - line('$'))
    execute 'normal!' "V'e="
    execute 'normal!' 'f(i     '
    execute a:line1 . ',' . l:line2 . 'Tabularize /{/' 
endfun
command! -range Reformat :call s:reformat(<line1>, <line2>)

"=================================================================="

" unformat single line if-statements into multiline if-statements
fun! s:unformat(line1, line2)

    " mark line one  &&  keep track of lines selected
    execute 'normal!' 'me'
    let l:numDiff = a:line2 - a:line1 + 1

    " delete extraneous white space
    execute 'normal!' 'f dt(i '
    let c = 0
    while c < numDiff - 1
        execute 'normal!' 'f)f dt{i '
        execute 'normal!' 'j0w'
        let c += 1
    endwhile
    execute 'normal!' 'f dt{i '

    " Formatting to make the statements span multiple lines
    execute 'normal!' "'e"
    execute 'normal!' . (a:line2 - a:line1 + 1) . 'J' 
    execute 's/{ /{\r/g'
    execute 'normal!' "'e"
    let c = 0
    while c < l:numDiff
        execute 'normal!' 'j'
        execute 's/}/\r}/g'
        let c += 1
    endwhile
    execute 'normal!' "V'e="
endfun
command! -range Unformat :call s:unformat(<line1>, <line2>)

"=================================================================="

" a smarter delete operation (does not copy whitespace into registers)
" NOTE: this doesn't prevent copying whitespace using 'yy' or 'Vy'
"       my assumption is that you wanted to copy the whitespace instead of deleting it

function! Smart_Delete_dd()
    let temp = getreg('"', 1)
    execute 'normal!' 'dd'
    if matchstr(@", '\_s*') == @"    " if just whitespace
        call setreg('"', temp)
        call setreg('*', temp)
        call setreg('+', temp)
        call setreg('0', temp)
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> dd :call Smart_Delete_dd()<CR>

function! Smart_Delete_Vd() range
    let temp = getreg('"', 1)
    execute 'normal!' . (a:lastline - a:firstline + 1) . 'dd'
    if matchstr(@", '\_s*') == @"    " if just whitespace
        call setreg('"', temp)
        call setreg('*', temp)
        call setreg('+', temp)
        call setreg('0', temp)
    endif
endfunction
vnoremap <silent> d :call Smart_Delete_Vd()<CR>

"=================================================================="

" insert the full path of the current file 
fun! s:fullpath()
    :put =expand('%:p')
endfun
command! FullPath :call s:fullpath()

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" ================= Begin my custom ';' commands =================="

" use ;zf to fold all functions (in C and C++ and Java)
function! FoldFunctions()
    :silent! execute "%g/^bool/normal! vf{%zf"
    :silent! execute "%g/^boolean/normal! vf{%zf"
    :silent! execute "%g/^int/normal! vf{%zf"
    :silent! execute "%g/^double/normal! vf{%zf"
    :silent! execute "%g/^void/normal! vf{%zf"

    :silent! execute "%g/\tbool/normal! vf{%zf"
    :silent! execute "%g/\tboolean/normal! vf{%zf"
    :silent! execute "%g/\tint/normal! vf{%zf"
    :silent! execute "%g/\tdouble/normal! vf{%zf"
    :silent! execute "%g/\tvoid/normal! vf{%zf"

    :silent! execute "%g/\tpublic/normal! vf{%zf"
    :silent! execute "%g/\tprivate/normal! vf{%zf"
endfunc
nnoremap ;zf zE :call FoldFunctions()<CR><ESC>

" use ;n to toggle between number mode and relative number mode
function! NumberToggle()
  if(&relativenumber == 1)
    set nornu
    set nonu
  else
    set rnu
    set nu
  endif
endfunc
nnoremap ;n :call NumberToggle()<CR>
set rnu
set nu

" use ;p to retain original indentation when pasting from another application
nnoremap ;p :set invpaste paste?<CR>
set showmode

" use ;w to remove trailing whitespace press ';w' (semicolon then 'w')
function! TrimWhitespace()
    let l:save_cursor = getpos('.')
    %s/\s\+$//e
    call setpos('.', l:save_cursor)
endfunction
nnoremap ;w :call TrimWhitespace()<CR>

" use ;h to toggle highlighted search
nnoremap ;h :set hlsearch! hlsearch?<CR>

" use ;l to reload the file
nnoremap ;l :e<CR>

" use ;t and type a file name to open it in a VIM tab (:tabnew)
nnoremap ;t :tabnew 

" use ;m to run the Makefile in the current directory (:make)
nnoremap ;m :make<CR>

" use ;s to source the vimrc file
nnoremap ;s :source $VIM/vimrc<CR>

" use ;f to format the file according to C++/Java style
nnoremap ;f :set expandtab! expandtab?<CR>gg=G''<ESC>

" use ;d to put deleted stuff in the black hole register "_
nnoremap ;d "_dd
vnoremap ;d "_d

" use ;j to jump from a function call to that function's definition
" use T  to pop from the tag stack and go to that location
" use in conjuction with ctags
nnoremap ;j <C-]>zz
nnoremap T <C-t>zz

" use ;y to copy the current text file into the clipboard
nnoremap ;y myggvG$"*y'y

" use ;v to paste from the clipboard
nnoremap ;v "*p

" use ;zf to easily fold code that lies in between the braces
" v%zf<CR>

" use ;r in visual mode to replace the visually selected word
nnoremap ;r ye:%s/<C-F>pa//g<ESC>F/i
vnoremap ;r y:%s/<C-F>pa//g<ESC>F/i

" ================================================================="
" ================================================================="
" ================== Some nice things to remember ================="

" restore color scheme --> this is not actually mapped to something
" set filetype=____   (e.g. :set filetype=cpp)

" zipping files
" zip -r file_name.zip *

" specific things for filetypes --> actually don't do this --> see ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/
" au FileType python 

" Don't wake up system with blinking cursor:
" http://www.linuxpowertop.org/known.php
let &guicursor = &guicursor . ",a:blinkon0"
```

Comment: What do you have in vimrc?

Comment: Oops forgot to put that in. @dlmeetei Edited as shown above

Comment: It's rather large and some of the things are pretty hacky, but as requested I edited the question to contain my entire vimrc @romainl